# Tkinter select menu label in menubutton

Tags: python, tkinter

To explain briefly, i have a code that i created a submenu in my app.

For my categories with subcategories, i create a menu again and add them with add_cascade with menu parameter.

On Windows, label with subcategories work to show the category, but clicking on the label does not happen. I can click on label if there is no subcategory

I can click Foo and Baz but can't click Bar

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('App')
        self.geometry('200x100')

        self.category_button = ttk.Menubutton(self, text='Select')
        self.category_button = self.create_categories_menu(self.category_button)

        self.category_button.pack(expand=True)

    def create_categories_menu(self, category_button):
        categories = {
            'Foo': {
                'ID': 1
            },
            'Bar': {
                'ID': 2,
                'SubCategory': {
                    'Baz': {
                        'ID': 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        top_menu = tk.Menu(category_button, tearoff=False)
        category_button.configure(menu=top_menu)

        self.create_sub_category(categories, category_button, top_menu)

        return category_button
    
    def create_sub_category(self, categories, category_button, top_menu):
        for category in categories:
            if ('SubCategory' not in categories[category]):
                top_menu.add_cascade(
                    label=category,
                    command=lambda c=category:
                        self.set_button_label(category_button, c)
                    )
            else:
                menu = tk.Menu(top_menu, tearoff=False)
                top_menu.add_cascade(
                    label=category,
                    menu=menu,
                    command=lambda c=category:
                        self.set_button_label(category_button, c)
                )

                self.create_sub_category(
                    categories[category]['SubCategory'],
                    category_button,
                    menu
                )
    
    def set_button_label(self, button, name):
        button.configure(text=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] instead of just a function which cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: It may be normal behaviour if there is a submenu attached.

Comment: It's work on macOS

Comment: Different platforms may have different behaviours.